# What's the difference between "ex-" and "former"

Tags: differences, adjectives, american-english, prefixes

Is there any real difference in usage between *ex-* and *former*?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you describe research have you done (e.g. dictionaries, quotations) as to where you do or don't see a distinction? You may also wish to visit the [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on asking answerable questions.

Answer (score 4):

My sense is that 'ex' carries just a slight note of dishonour, whereas 'former' carries no such nuance.

One speaks of 'former' Prime Ministers, and Presidents. I've never heard anyone speak of an ex-President, even of those that did behave dishonourably.

If a person was speaking of their 'ex-huband' or 'ex-wife', it would suggest to me that they were implying disfavour. 'My former wife' sounds softer.

An ex-clergyman sounds to me like one who has been 'unfrocked', a 'former clergyman' one who has retired; similarly with policemen.

Comment: I would agree, with the addendum that "ex-" seems like someone was forcibly removed from the state, where as "former" seems like a natural transition.

Comment: I don't disagree with your take, but I found a [relevant Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ex-president%2Cformer+president&year_start=1820&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cex%20-%20president%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cformer%20president%3B%2Cc0) rather interesting. It seems like _ex-_ was favored (at least in writing) up through the early 20th c.  Benj. Harrison (or his publisher) even opted to entitle a 1901 collection of his speeches [_Views of an ex-president_](http://books.google.com/books?id=ta1YAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22ex+president%22&source=gbs_navlinks_s).

Answer (score 0):

Another take is that "ex" is a compound form, while "former" is an adjective.  That would be "the difference in usage".  But they both mean the same thing.

I don't think "ex" has a negative connotation.

Perhaps, in the President/Prime Minister case, "former" implies that he's still living.

On the other hand, no-one refers to the former spouse as "former husband (or wife)".

It's just one of those peculiarities of English.  Nuances abound.

Comment: Conversationally, I agree that _ex-wife_ seems much more common that _former wife_. In writing, though, the use of _former_ doesn't seem so rare. Here's an [interesting Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ex-husband%2Cex-wife%2Cformer+husband%2Cformer+wife&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cex%20-%20husband%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cex%20-%20wife%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cformer%20husband%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cformer%20wife%3B%2Cc0).